# Expansion of Homogeneous Universe using Fluid Dynamics

Tags: homework-and-exercises, fluid-dynamics, gravity, cosmology, space-expansion

In the MIT OCW course [The Early Universe](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/physics/8-286-the-early-universe-fall-2013/) Prof. Alan Guth justifies the use of Newtonian gravity to approximately describe the homogeneous expansion of the universe, (at least a matter dominated one) and uses it to to derive the Friedmann equation. He also shows that if the universe is homogeneous at the initial time of the resulting DE ( which really is an arbitrary time.) it is homogeneous throughout.

I thought it should be possible to do the same thing by modelling it as a fluid  and get the same results.Assuming isotropy and a pressureless, iniscid fluid and using shperical coordinates I ended up with the following equations after a little simplification:

$$\frac{\partial \rho}{\partial t}+\frac{\partial \rho V_r}{\partial r}=-\frac{2\rho V_r}{r} \hspace{2.5cm} (continuity) $$

$$\frac{\partial V_r}{\partial t}+V_r\frac{\partial V_r}{\partial r}=\mathbf{f}_r \hspace{3cm} (momentum)$$

$$\mathbf{f}_r=-\frac{4\pi G}{3}\rho r\hspace{4cm}(gravity)$$
Where $V_r(r,t)$ & $\rho(r,t)$ are the radial velocity  and density respectively and the initial condition as $V_r=Hr$ at $t=o$. I should also clarify the gravitational term: since  the universe is isotropic, the force felt at any point can only be radial so the force of the sphere centered at the origin with radius $r$ is substituted.

I thought it would be easy to solve since it such a special case but try what I may, I haven't been able to find any physical argument that helps to solve them.

What I want to ask is have I made any error in this approach so far? and if not then how to solve the equations (using physical arguments or otherwise)?!

$\textbf P.S.$ *I don't think it's necessary to watch the lecture series to understand the question,though it helps understand my motivation. I think Newtonian universes are accepted as a valid introductory level approximation and are even used in some textbooks, even though the R-W metric description is more accurate, so lets keep the discussion about this model for now.*

Comment: Note that with fluid dynamics, typically one has to numerically solve it (e.g., using finite difference/volume/element methods).

Comment: @KyleKanos but this isn't a typical situation right? we already know it has an exact solution (I checked it by substituting the known matter dominated solution). So there must be some clever way to solve this using fluid dynamic interpretations.

Comment: if you're wondering why I'm doing this in spite of knowing the answer, I'm doing it as a self excercise just to strengthen my understanding and also just for curiosity/fun.